# Javascript: dynamic import() multiple function from one module

Tags: javascript, import, dynamic, gulp

using a non module gulpfile I managed to import a function from the node "del" module (which doesn't support require() any more) this way:

```
const del = (...args) => import('del').then((mod) => mod.deleteAsync(...args));
```

Is it possible to import multiple functions in on line of code, or do I have to repeat this line by line like

```
const delSync = (...args) => import('del').then((mod) => mod.deleteSync(...args));
...
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the real answer to my question.
Since the dynamic import question arose during setup of a new project I decided to go on with ES module syntax. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

```
const {
  delSync,
  del
} = await import('del');
```

Comment: Thx, but I get an error with that code:
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules